# Present am getting content on same div on hover, i want content should show on next div on hover the first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Present am getting content on same div on hover, I want content should show on next div on hover the first div.[required output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW8xf.png),please help on this issue. In this output we have four boxes, 2X2 boxes, I want content should show on next box on hover
In this code, I just used HTML and CSS so I want small change in this , just show the content on next div on hover

```css
.four-divs {
  width: 322px;
  height: 151px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.four-divs img {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.global-mobility-strategy {
  float: left;
}

.assignment-policy-reference {
  float: right;
}

.client-projrct-tools {
  float: left;
}

.additional-assignment-references {
  float: right;
}

.mobility-opportunities {
  width: 100%;
  height: 151px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.four-divs .inner-div-content {
  align-content: center;
}

.inner-div-content h3 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* font-family: open sand; */
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.mobility-opportunities img {
  width: 13%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image-container {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container .mask,
.image-container .content {
  width: 322px;
  height: 151px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container a.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white !important;
  padding: 6px 13px;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.effect .mask {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  // transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.effect a.info {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  /* Center the link */
  opacity: 0;
  //  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
}

.effect:hover .mask {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #86BC25;
}

.effect:hover .mask h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  //padding: 6px;
  background-color: #86BC25;
  height: 30px;
}

.effect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  //transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-four-divs">
  <div class="hover-div" style="width: 650px;
        height: 315px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF; ">

    <div class="global-mobility-strategy image-container four-divs effect">
      <div class="inner-div-content">
        <img src="icon-22.jpg" alt="Global Mobility Strategy" />
        <h3 style="line-height: 23px; font-weight: bold;"> Communications </h3>
        <img src="arrow-new.jpg" alt="arrow" style="
        width: 5%;
        margin: -23px 0px -2px 296px;
    ">
      </div>

      <div class="mask">
        <h3>Communications Toolkit</h3>
        <p style="height: 62px;margin: 10px 0px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-top: 13px;">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="assignment-policy-reference image-container four-divs effect">
      <div class="inner-div-content">
        <img src="icon-22.jpg" alt="Assignment Policy References" />
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;font-weight: bold;">Assignment </h3>
        <img src="arrow-new.jpg" alt="arrow" style="
        width: 5%;
        margin: -10px 0px -2px 296px;
    ">
      </div>
      <div class="mask">

        <h3>Assignment</h3>
        <p style="height: 62px;margin: 28px 0px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-top: -4px;">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s

        </p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="client-projrct-tools image-container four-divs effect">
      <div class="inner-div-content">
        <img src="icon-22.jpg" alt="Client Project Tools" />
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;font-weight: bold;">Client Project</h3>
        <img src="arrow-new.jpg" alt="arrow" style="
        width: 5%;
        margin: -10px 0px -2px 296px;
    ">
      </div>
      <div class="mask">
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;">Client Project </h3>
        <p style="height: 62px;margin: 10px 0px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-top: 13px;">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="additional-assignment-references image-container four-divs effect">
      <div class="inner-div-content">
        <img src="icon-22.jpg" alt="Additional Assignment References" />
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;font-weight: bold;">Additional Assignment References</h3>
        <img src="arrow-new.jpg" alt="arrow" style="
        width: 5%;
        margin: -10px 0px -2px 296px;
    ">
      </div>
      <div class="mask">
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;">Additional</h3>
        <p style="height: 62px;margin: 10px 0px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-top: 13px;">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s .</p>

        <a href="#" class="info">Read more</a>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want "communication" hover content shows on "assignment" tab with hover effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by simply modify and add some `CSS`. You can change overlay box position using `transform: translateX();` `CSS` when you hover the parent. And set negative position of overlay using `nth-child(even)` `CSS`

**Here is Demo**

```css
.four-divs {
    width: 322px;
    height: 151px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.four-divs img {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.global-mobility-strategy {
    float: left;
}
.assignment-policy-reference {
    float: right;
}
.client-projrct-tools {
    float: left;
}
.additional-assignment-references {
    float: right;
}
.mobility-opportunities {
    width: 100%;
    height: 151px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.four-divs .inner-div-content {
    align-content: center;
}
.inner-div-content h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    /* font-family: open sand; */
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.mobility-opportunities img {
    width: 13%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.image-container {
    float: left;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    position: relative;
}
.image-container .mask,
.image-container .content {
    width: 322px;
    height: 151px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.image-container img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.image-container a.info {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 6px 13px;
    text-align: center !important;
}
.effect .mask {
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    // transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.effect a.info {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    /* Center the link */
    opacity: 0;
    //  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
}
.effect:hover .mask {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: #86BC25;

    transform: translateX(100%);
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
.effect:nth-child(even):hover .mask {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.effect:hover .mask h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    //padding: 6px;
    background-color: #86BC25;
    height: 30px;
}
.effect:hover a.info {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    //transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-four-divs">
  <div class="hover-div" style="width: 650px; height: 315px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
    <div class="global-mobility-strategy image-container four-divs effect">
      <div class="inner-div-content">
        <img src="icon-22.jpg" alt="Global Mobility Strategy" />
        <h3 style="line-height: 23px; font-weight: bold;"> Communications </h3>
        <img src="arrow-new.jpg" alt="arrow" style="width: 5%; margin: -23px 0px -2px 296px;">
      </div>
      <div class="mask">
        <h3>Communications Toolkit</h3>
        <p style="height: 62px;margin: 10px 0px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-top: 13px;">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="assignment-policy-reference image-container four-divs effect">
      <div class="inner-div-content">
        <img src="icon-22.jpg" alt="Assignment Policy References" />
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;font-weight: bold;">Assignment </h3>
        <img src="arrow-new.jpg" alt="arrow" style="width: 5%; margin: -10px 0px -2px 296px;">
      </div>
      <div class="mask">
        <h3>Assignment</h3>
        <p style="height: 62px;margin: 28px 0px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-top: -4px;">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="client-projrct-tools image-container four-divs effect">
      <div class="inner-div-content">
        <img src="icon-22.jpg" alt="Client Project Tools" />
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;font-weight: bold;">Client Project</h3>
        <img src="arrow-new.jpg" alt="arrow" style="width: 5%; margin: -10px 0px -2px 296px;">
      </div>
      <div class="mask">
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;">Client Project </h3>
        <p style="height: 62px;margin: 10px 0px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-top: 13px;">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="additional-assignment-references image-container four-divs effect">
      <div class="inner-div-content">
        <img src="icon-22.jpg" alt="Additional Assignment References" />
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;font-weight: bold;">Additional Assignment References</h3>
        <img src="arrow-new.jpg" alt="arrow" style="width: 5%; margin: -10px 0px -2px 296px;">
      </div>
      <div class="mask">
        <h3 style="line-height: 35px;">Additional</h3>
        <p style="height: 62px;margin: 10px 0px;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;margin-top: 13px;">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s .</p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tq so much ...my Issue resloved

Comment: @teja.sandela Plz upvote and mark as right answer if it's the right answer.